# Getting the number of elements in a C array

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a C function, but when I compile it with -Wall flag, it complains as follows:

> warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘dayarray’ will return
> size of ‘const long int *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]

#### C Function

```
static int get_month_and_day(const long dayarray[], const size_t dayofyear, long* month, long* dayofmonth)
{
    unsigned char found = 0 ;
    const size_t numelements  = (sizeof dayarray)/ (sizeof *dayarray) ;
    ...
}
```

What would be a better way of determing the number of elements in the variable `dayarray` ?.

Comment: You have to keep track of it from the function that makes the array. Pass the length as an additional parameter